# Error converting data type DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP to datetime2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, filemaker

I have this code

```
SELECT
TRY_CONVERT(varchar(150), "PCR_Fecha")  AS "PCR_Fecha"
FROM OPENQUERY(EXTRACCION, 'SELECT * FROM EXTRACCION.Extraccion')
```

But i get the error

```
Error converting data type DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP to datetime2.
```

I know there are wrong values in PCR_Fecha (like 40218:00:00 or 14mayo09) that's why I'm trying to convert them to varchar.

I can see the data using

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(EXTRACCION, 'SELECT CAST(PCR_Fecha AS varchar(26)) FROM EXTRACCION.Extraccion');
```

The linked server is from Filemaker and there PCR_Fecha is set as a date.
Looking for an answer I found that I could define "dbtimestamp_rules=2" in connection string but I don't know how to add the rule.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I could change the data type from Filemaker and set it to text (it was date before) and that solves the problem.

With sql it was

```
SELECT
Convert(NVARCHAR(26),PCR_Fecha)
FROM OPENQUERY(EXTRACCION, 'SELECT CAST(PCR_Fecha AS VARCHAR(26)) as PCR_Fecha FROM EXTRACCION.Extraccion')
```

A cast and then convert, anyways thx :)